# Что нужно знать перед cозданием социальной сети?

Tags: android, google-play, social-network, gdpr

Где можно почитать про "что нужно знать перед cозданием социальной сети". Я имею ввиду условия использование, гдпр, политика конфиденциальности и может ещё что то о чем я недогадываюсь.
Почти готово приложение на андроид которое входит в категорию, социальные сети, там присутствует регистрация.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> условия использование, гдпр, политика конфиденциальности

Про это всё нужно не только читать, но и грамотно составить. Если у вас нет юридического образования в нужных (международных) сферах, то обратитесь к профессионалам (специализирующихся именно на данных вопросах), для составления ПК, ГДПР и УИ (да, это всё довольно дорого). Эти 3 документа (иногда их объединяют в 1 или 2) - самое главное и важное. Они регламентирует взаимоотношение между вами и пользователями. От них так же будет зависеть то, сколько с вас смогут содрать денег в разных судах в случае чего (а это, поверьте, реально и важно)...

Но наличие этих документов - это не единственное что нужно. Вам нужно обеспечить защиту конфиденциальных данных пользователей (например, вы не должны хранить пароли в чистом виде, только хэш и т.п.), чего большинство всех сайтов и приложений не делают.

Так же вам придётся соответствовать всем условиям в ваших же документах. Условно говоря, если написано, что передача данных осуществляется по зашифрованному соединению с использованием протокола HTTPS версии 2, а вдруг окажется что вы используете httpsv1.2 - то тут уже нарушение и вероятность получить иск...

И ещё (вы должны уже это знать, но на всякий случай напишу)... Для пользователей из ЕС (и ещё каких-то там стран (список можно найти в гугле)) ДО начала сбора любой информации о пользователе, вы должны спросить его согласие на сбор персонализированных данных (да же если вы собираете только не персонализированные данные - вы должны предупредить его об этом). И более того, у пользователей должна быть возможность получить ВСЕ данные о себе, которые есть у вас и у ваших партнёров. И ещё хуже - они могут потребовать удалить ВСЕ данные о себе и вы обязаны будите это сделать.

Продолжать можно много, смысл в том, что если вы хотите распространять приложение и зарабатывать на нём официально - то, всё это придётся делать и выполнять, и хорошенько проконсультироваться с юристами. Если нет - то...

Comment: А еще персональные данные российских пользователей должны храниться в России.